# Mongodb user is able use databases without privileges

Tags: mongodb

I have two databases (staging and production). Also, I have 2 users (staging_user and production_user). But User staging_user can use the production database after login.

```
mongo --authenticationDatabase staging -u staging_user -p ***********

> use production
switched to db production

>db.getName()
production

> show collections
accounts

> db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1})
{
    "authInfo" : {
        "authenticatedUsers" : [
            {
                "user" : "staging_user",
                "db" : "staging"
            }
        ],
        "authenticatedUserRoles" : [
            {
                "role" : "readWrite",
                "db" : "staging"
            }
        ]
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

getSiblingDb result:

```
{
    "role" : "readWrite",
    "db" : "gepick_staging",
    "isBuiltin" : true,
    "roles" : [ ],
    "inheritedRoles" : [ ],
    "privileges" : [
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "staging",
                "collection" : ""
            },
            "actions" : [
                "changeStream",
                "collStats",
                "convertToCapped",
                "createCollection",
                "createIndex",
                "dbHash",
                "dbStats",
                "dropCollection",
                "dropIndex",
                "emptycapped",
                "find",
                "insert",
                "killCursors",
                "listCollections",
                "listIndexes",
                "planCacheRead",
                "remove",
                "renameCollectionSameDB",
                "update"
            ]
        },
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "staging",
                "collection" : "system.indexes"
            },
            "actions" : [
                "changeStream",
                "collStats",
                "dbHash",
                "dbStats",
                "find",
                "killCursors",
                "listCollections",
                "listIndexes",
                "planCacheRead"
            ]
        },
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "staging",
                "collection" : "system.js"
            },
            "actions" : [
                "changeStream",
                "collStats",
                "convertToCapped",
                "createCollection",
                "createIndex",
                "dbHash",
                "dbStats",
                "dropCollection",
                "dropIndex",
                "emptycapped",
                "find",
                "insert",
                "killCursors",
                "listCollections",
                "listIndexes",
                "planCacheRead",
                "remove",
                "renameCollectionSameDB",
                "update"
            ]
        },
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "staging",
                "collection" : "system.namespaces"
            },
            "actions" : [
                "changeStream",
                "collStats",
                "dbHash",
                "dbStats",
                "find",
                "killCursors",
                "listCollections",
                "listIndexes",
                "planCacheRead"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "inheritedPrivileges" : [
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "staging",
                "collection" : ""
            },
            "actions" : [
                "changeStream",
                "collStats",
                "convertToCapped",
                "createCollection",
                "createIndex",
                "dbHash",
                "dbStats",
                "dropCollection",
                "dropIndex",
                "emptycapped",
                "find",
                "insert",
                "killCursors",
                "listCollections",
                "listIndexes",
                "planCacheRead",
                "remove",
                "renameCollectionSameDB",
                "update"
            ]
        },
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "staging",
                "collection" : "system.indexes"
            },
            "actions" : [
                "changeStream",
                "collStats",
                "dbHash",
                "dbStats",
                "find",
                "killCursors",
                "listCollections",
                "listIndexes",
                "planCacheRead"
            ]
        },
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "staging",
                "collection" : "system.js"
            },
            "actions" : [
                "changeStream",
                "collStats",
                "convertToCapped",
                "createCollection",
                "createIndex",
                "dbHash",
                "dbStats",
                "dropCollection",
                "dropIndex",
                "emptycapped",
                "find",
                "insert",
                "killCursors",
                "listCollections",
                "listIndexes",
                "planCacheRead",
                "remove",
                "renameCollectionSameDB",
                "update"
            ]
        },
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "staging",
                "collection" : "system.namespaces"
            },
            "actions" : [
                "changeStream",
                "collStats",
                "dbHash",
                "dbStats",
                "find",
                "killCursors",
                "listCollections",
                "listIndexes",
                "planCacheRead"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How don`t allow staging_user to use the production database?

Comment: Did you grant any additional privileges to this role? Check with `db.getSiblingDB("staging").getRole( "readWrite", { showBuiltinRoles: true, showPrivileges: true } )`

Comment: Make sure [security.authorization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#security.authorization) is set to enabled

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit updated post with getSiblingDB result

Comment: fixed by @Joe suggestion. Db authorization was disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure, you have enabled **auth** in config and **restart** mongodb.

For more details, Please follow below link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#security.authorization